# "Clear User Data" android

Tags: android

What exactly does Clear User Data do? I mean I know it clears the users data from the app, but what data being stored where?

Comment: I assume you mean Manifest.permission CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA

Comment: Yea i guess, but what data are we clearing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a permissions that applications can hold.

It is there for the settings app's "Clear data" button in manage applications.  It simply erases all of the data in internal storage associated with the app, bringing it back to its initial install state.

Comment: Referred to permission is `CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA`

Comment: Alright so it deletes all data associated with the app, but "which" data. For example where is this data located and how does one set to this data path using this application? 

Or is this referring to all data (SD card/Cache/SQL)

Comment: Everything in the application's internal data directory.  Nothing on the SD card is touched.  (We'll be defining standard places for app data on external storage in the future that does get cleaned up; this is something that is really needed.)

Comment: Except native libraries in the libs directory

Comment: Native libraries in the libs directory are not "data", that is just the code pulled out of the .apk.

Answer (score 6):

This "CLEAR DATA" option is severely broken for the use-case of Home Screen widgets that may have shared preferences and/or some local cached data.

It is also completely against the developer documentation which says:

"You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed."

It would be good if answers to valid questions actually offered some useful advice, like a work-around or some method that achieves the result being sought by the question.

So, what happens to a Home Screen widget that has shared preferences and then the user clears the data? Any useful suggestion how not to break the running code of the widget when it has the data pulled away without any notice?

Comment: We had the same issue, and could not find a way to capture the "Clear data" intent. Also, in order not to break the running code, we had to defend ourselves with a lot of if-then-else conditions. But even if you've dont nothing, the user is responsible for clearing data, so he should know he done something that was not a normal condition.

Comment: @Henrique de Sousa But what if it isnt the user deleting the data. What if it is a malicious person or a baby? There should be some permission code on clear data request.

Comment: It should, but (imho) it won't, as it may break a lot of stuff. My sugestion continues to apply: defend your app with conditions, you may even change the text on the Widget warning the user to re-configure it again.