# Android - Preventing Application data or files being deleted thru "Clear Data" settings option

Tags: android

I have an Android application that stores about 25-40K of private app data in few files. By default system stores these files in the directory /data/data/'my app package'/files. When the user goes to "Setting->Applications->Manage Applications->'My app package'" and chooses the "Clear data" option, all the files, databases folders for this app is being deleted. I need to keep my data on the device until the app is "uninstalled".

Is there a way to keep my application data "on the device" somewhere without being deleted? My device is not rooted. My app is not meant to be on rooted devices.

Note: I saw the /data/data/'my app package'/lib directory is not being deleted using the "clear data" option. But I couldn't programmatically write to this direcroty. I get permission denied. Is there a way to use this directory to store my data? Is there a way to use NDK (not worked on it yet) to keep the data safe? Is there a way to keep the data in application resource or something like a DLL resource in Windows programing.

Any help please to get me out of this jam?

Comment: Using the NDK wouldn't get you past any write-permission issues that you are hitting in your Java code.

Comment: What type of data are you looking to keep? I would expect any user who clears the data to expect data loss. A possible solution is to keep some data in cacheDir (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29), as this is cleared separately. It may also be viable to store data on the SD card.

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestions all of you. I trying keep some simple corporate secure text data. They will be encrypted of course. The cahce dir seems to be unsafe too; doc says it will be deleted on low memory. SD card can be removed by the user and may not put back for a long time. Keeping the data on the server; issue is device may not be in touch with server for long times due to out of service, out of range etc.

Answer (score 11):

The following works for me: `android:manageSpaceActivity=".ActivityOfMyChoice"`

Then instead of `"Clear Data"`, there is a button for `"Manage Space"` which launches `ActivityOfMyChoice`

It's working for my app, and I see it working on Dolphin Browser (which is what prompted me to find this info).

I'm using a Samsung Captivate (AT&T Galaxy S) with stock 2.2 (Froyo). I don't know if some devices might display both, or not.

Some devices may still display both, or may just not show Manage Space at all

Answer (score 2):

> When the user goes to "Setting->Applications->Manage Applications->'My app package'" and chooses the "Clear data" option, all the files, databases folders for this app is being deleted. I need to keep my data on the device until the app is "uninstalled".

This isn't possible for security reasons, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196582/clear-user-data-android/2198342#2198342) question.

Answer (score 2):

Add

> android:allowClearUserData="false"

to Application tag of the manifiest 
it will change the button **Clear Data** to **Manage Space**

Comment: As per the doc this is only usable by apps bundled with system image.

Comment: "This attribute is usable only by applications included in the system image. Third-party apps cannot use."