# Receive intent when user clears data

Tags: android

is it possible to receive some intent, when user clicks "Clear data" button in Manage Application section while app is running?

Answer (score 0):

Clear data clears the SharedPreferences files and all database storages. 
Take a look here: ["Clear User Data" android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196582/clear-user-data-android)

To my knowledge there is no intent to recieve when the user does this, you simply must act accordingly in case this happens.

Comment: I know that it's cleaning SharedPreferences. The question is: is it possible to check that data is cleared while app is running?

Comment: Sorry your question was not clear to me ... now I understand, you would like to get an intent when the user does this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is an old thread, but I thought I'd share the solution I came up with for such a case.

SharedPreferences.get methods require a defaultValue to be supplied. Instead of using a boolean for first_time, I used an integer, returning -1 as defaultValue. If defaultValue is returned, it means the preference was not found, meaning first time app use (or data cleared, or your app called remove() or clear() on the SharedPreferences).

It's not very elegant, but it does the trick.