# Data don't deleted from user

Tags: android, storage

In Android it is possible to reset the data on the application by clicking on "Clear Data" in the settings.
In my application I need that the user can not delete the data that are generated by the application. Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196582/clear-user-data-android/2198342#2198342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can backup the data in the cloud and map the data with device IMEI... then whenever you don't find data locally just fetch it from server...

Or you can store you data on the sdcard this would save you data being deleted at the time of `clear data`... but user can always delete stuff from sdcard also..

So if you have critical data then saving it on cloud is the best option..

Comment: I need that the user can not delete the data just as I have no active connection. I believe that to save the data of SD is the only solution.

Comment: you can use SdCard as the first level on backup.. and cloud as second level of backup..

Answer (score 0):

There is a provision to replace the clear Data button with the  "Manage Space" which launches ActivityOfMyChoice. Code snippet as follows:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:manageSpaceActivity=".MyOwnActivity"
...

  <activity
    android:name=".MyOwnActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

it will call MyOwnActivity:

```
//Destroy the activity in onCeate
public class MyOwnActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            MyOwnActivity.this.finish();

    }
}
```

Give it a try and see if it works.